# Problema ao publicar site no iis feito em angularjs

Tags: angularjs, iis

Estou tentando publicar um site em angularjs no iis porem após a publicação, quando vou acessa-lo, ele me retorna no console o seguinte erro :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em desenvolvimento este erro não ocorre...

Minha estrutura esta a seguinte

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu config esta assim :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso pode ocorrer na hora da minificação do código, quando suas injeções de dependências nos controllers não estão na forma "Strict-di".

Verifique se seus controllers e também serviços estão todos seguindo o mesmo padrão, que seria:

O correto:

```
.controller('NomeController', ["$scope", "$rootScope", function($scope, $rootScope) {

}]);
```

Ao invés de:

```
.controller('NomeController', function($scope, $rootScope, etc...) {

});
```

Para verificar se todos os controllers estão anotados corretamente, sem ter que minificar ou testar em produção, insira o o atributo "ng-strict-di" no elemento que contém o ng-app, ou se faz o bootstrap pelo script, adicione o parâmetro referente a isso na inicialização do app.

Por exemplo:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
```